# algorithm giving an unexpected argument in requests_http_signature library

Tags: python, python-requests

In the below code I'm attempting to use the, 'RSA_V1_5_SHA256', algorithm to create a signature for connecting to an API. However, despite the documentation having it written this way, it doesn't seem to recognize algorithm as a valid argument.

Here's the documentation linked as well,
https://pyauth.github.io/requests-http-signature/#asymmetric-key-algorithms

```
auth = HTTPSignatureAuth(
    algorithm=algorithms.RSA_V1_5_SHA256, key=preshared_secret, key_id=signature_key_id
)
```

This is the specific error that's being returned,
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'algorithm'`.

I assume perhaps the documentation may be outdated, as I need to pass a passphrase that was used when I created the public and private keys, to properly authenticate my requests to said API... and passphrase/password isn't an acceptable argument in the other available algorithms based on what I've seen in the source code for this library.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like they've since updated the documentation, as well as updated the source code to include that algorithm argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're totally right and the docs aren't updated, by checking the [source code](https://github.com/pyauth/requests-http-signature/blob/198e2dae5c253f471fa66759f77cea600c0a8fb9/requests_http_signature/__init__.py#L86) we can see that the `__init__` method for the `HTTPSignatureAuth` class has no `algorithm` argument. Instead we find a `signature_algorithm` parameter  (also we can see that this is the parameter that we need - [source](https://github.com/pyauth/requests-http-signature/blob/198e2dae5c253f471fa66759f77cea600c0a8fb9/requests_http_signature/__init__.py#L41)) so I would go with that:

```py
auth = HTTPSignatureAuth(
    signature_algorithm=algorithms.RSA_V1_5_SHA256, key=preshared_secret, key_id=signature_key_id
)
```

The changes were made in version [`v0.3.0`](https://github.com/pyauth/requests-http-signature/compare/v0.3.0...develop) so if you use a previous version you will be able to use `algorithm` as the argument. But I would go with the first approach. (Note that version `v0.3.0` was released 23 days ago so it's pretty recent and they may update the docs soon!